# bash calling executable No such file or directory

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash    
DIR=$(dirname "$0")
GPIO=$DIR/gpio-output
FPGACHECK=$("$GPIO -0" 2>&1)
echo $FPGACHECK

line 2: ./gpio-output -0: No such file or directory
```

I am trying to call this binary that is located in the same folder as the script i cant seem to make it run, I have tried darn near everything using the 'eval' command works but I dont think I get get the output of the binary into a string with that?

Comment: I should mention .. the binary is in the same directory and works fine i can call the binary like this `$GPIO 0` with no issue just cant pass the output to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave the `-0` outside the quotes. With it inside, that's treated as part of the binary's filename (rather than an argument to the binary). Also, you should also double-quote the string to be echoed, like this:

```
FPGACHECK=$("$GPIO" -0 2>&1)
echo "$FPGACHECK"
```

... or if you don't need `FPGACHECK` for anything else, simplify it by just letting the binary's output go directly to the terminal, rather than capturing its output to a variable and echoing that:

```
"$GPIO" -0
```

Another thing: is the argument supposed to be "-0", or just "0" as you say in the comment?

Comment: I do need to capture it to evaluate it, when I do it that way `FPGACHECK=$("$GPIO" 0 2>&1);
echo "$FPGACHECK"` no ouput is seen